# Rails code generated with ORM mangomapper throws NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "4d2aeaea4403baa84a000005":String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, mongodb-ruby

I am absolutely totally news to Rails and to MongoDB. I have been following tutorials from a good book and create my first Rails app with a light Twitter copy. Everything went fine and smooth.

But as part of my learning process I wanted to build the same app using MongoDB rather than the default SGBD.

I therefore configured mongo and installed the mongo_mapper gem. Everything has been configured properly following this tutorial: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started. Then I struggled a little bit to allow Rails generate to work without throwing me the --orm not specified error. In order to get past this I had to add the rails3-generators gem and add it to the Gemfile.

Once all this was done, everything worked fine. I was able to successfully launch the Rails server.

I added a User controller thanks to the generate. The page works fine and even lists the users I have previously added:

[image]

However all the other actions, showing, editing, deleting, etc. are not working (creating works, but then it goes to show and the errors comes):

[image]

It's virtually the same error for all different actions.

The one difference I can notice right off the bat is that with the non MongoDB db, the id's of the user was starting at 1, etc. but here with MongoDB it looks like a randomly generated id that is much more complex and that is not of type int: 4d2ae91d4403baa84a000002

I am thinking that this may be creating the issues, since all action are using the id as a parameter... but I have no idea how to fix this. I have looked at the ruby generated code and it looks alright to me (extremely similar to the code generate for the default db).

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! I don't know how to go forward with my project without solving a simple generate code with mongodb.

Thanks,

Alex

ps:
please that I did not write any of this code at all. everything has been generated, which is kinda why I expected to work from the get go...

as asked here is the code for users_controllers:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.xml
  def index
    @users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.xml
  def show
@user = User.first(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.xml
  def new
@user = User.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
end
  end

# GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
@user = User.first(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.xml
  def update
@user = User.first(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.xml
  def destroy
@user = User.first(params[:id])
@user.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
  end
end
```

Comment: Show us line 16 of `users_controller.rb` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hummm so it seems I found the pb...

I replaced:

```
@user = User.first(params[:id])
```

by

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

But again, this code was generated... so where does the error come from ? Is there a "bug" in rails3-generators ? Or somehow I screwed up the generation ?

Alex

Comment: Yes, it is a bug in rails3-generators. I've submitted the [fix](https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators/pull/9).